# How do I incorporate functions into functions with inputs?

Tags: python, function, input

I'm attempting to create a working address book and am stuck on creating the home page portion. In my code I try to use the child - parent inheritance yet it does not work. Help? Any other tips for the address book would be apprecciated. Thanks!

```
class Parent:
    def Create():
        create_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to create.
                           ''')
        addressbook.append(create_contact)
        print("Successfully added")
        return
    def Remove_contact(remove_contact):
        remove_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to remove.
                            ''')
        if 'remove_contact' in addressbook:
            print(addressbook.remove(remove_contact))
        else:
            print("Error, 'search_contact' not found in the list")
        return remove_contact
    def Search():
        search_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to search for.
                            ''')
        if 'search_contact' in addressbook:
            print("'search_contact' found in Address Book")
        else:
            print("Error, 'search_contact' not found in the list")
        return
    def Display_contacts():
        print("Displaying contacts....", addressbook)
        return

def menu(Parent):
    menu = input('''Address book to store friends contact
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   Select an option...
   1 - Add/Update contact...
   2 - Display all contacts...
   3 - Search...
   4 - Delete contact...
   5 - Quit
    ''')
    
    if menu == '1':
        Create()
    
    elif menu == '2':
        Display_contacts()
        
    elif menu == '3':
        Search()
        
    elif menu == '4':
        Remove_contact(remove_contact)
        
    elif menu == '5':
        print("Quitting program")
        quit()
    else:
        print("I did not understand that... Please try again")
        

menu(Parent)
```

Comment: But what is exactly the problem?

Comment: When I run the code it just stops after the input, it doesn't run the other function.

Comment: A child class has to be a class. You are just passing <class '\_\_main\_\_.Parent'> as an argument to menu()

Comment: so would it be: class Child(Parent):
                                   menu(Parent)

Comment: you have to pass an instance of Parent i.e. Parent() to the menu() call. Also I don't think inheritance is a good approach here, I would embed all of that in a single class and define a method that prompts the user and calls the right function accordingly.

Comment: How would you go about embedding it in a single class? I'm new to python and haven't seen this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before, it is not apparent that you need inheritance. Create an instance of Parent and reference it like this.

```
p = Parent()
```

You can then pass the instance p to menu.

```
menu(p)
```

You have to make a few changes to your class and method as well.

```
addressbook = []
class Parent:
    def Create(self):
        create_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to create.
                           ''')
        addressbook.append(create_contact)
        print("Successfully added")
        return
    def Remove_contact(self, remove_contact):
        remove_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to remove.
                            ''')
        if 'remove_contact' in addressbook:
            print(addressbook.remove(remove_contact))
        else:
            print("Error, 'search_contact' not found in the list")
        return remove_contact
    def Search(self):
        search_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to search for.
                            ''')
        if 'search_contact' in addressbook:
            print("'search_contact' found in Address Book")
        else:
            print("Error, 'search_contact' not found in the list")
        return
    def Display_contacts(self):
        print("Displaying contacts....", addressbook)
        return

def menu(parent):
    menu = input('''Address book to store friends contact
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   Select an option...
   1 - Add/Update contact...
   2 - Display all contacts...
   3 - Search...
   4 - Delete contact...
   5 - Quit
    ''')

    if menu == '1':
        parent.Create()

    elif menu == '2':
        parent.Display_contacts()

    elif menu == '3':
        parent.Search()

    elif menu == '4':
        parent.Remove_contact(remove_contact)

    elif menu == '5':
        print("Quitting program")
        parent.quit()
    else:
        print("I did not understand that... Please try again")

p = Parent()
menu(p)
```

This will get your program a little further along... It might make sense to make addressbook an attribute of your Parent class which maybe should be called AddressBook.

Also, read about python classes https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code. You forgot to add the class from which the functions derive.

```
addressbook = []
class Parent:
    def Create():
        create_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to create.
                           ''')
        addressbook.append(create_contact)
        print("Successfully added")
        return
    def Remove_contact(remove_contact):
        remove_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to remove.
                            ''')
        if 'remove_contact' in addressbook:
            print(addressbook.remove(remove_contact))
        else:
            print("Error, 'search_contact' not found in the list")
        return remove_contact
    def Search():
        search_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to search for.
                            ''')
        if 'search_contact' in addressbook:
            print("'search_contact' found in Address Book")
        else:
            print("Error, 'search_contact' not found in the list")
        return
    def Display_contacts():
        print("Displaying contacts....", addressbook)
        return

def menu(Parent):
    menu = input('''Address book to store friends contact
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   Select an option...
   1 - Add/Update contact...
   2 - Display all contacts...
   3 - Search...
   4 - Delete contact...
   5 - Quit
    ''')
    
    if menu == '1':
        Parent.Create()
    
    elif menu == '2':
        Parent.Display_contacts()
        
    elif menu == '3':
        Parent.Search()
        
    elif menu == '4':
        Parent.Remove_contact(Parent.remove_contact)
        
    elif menu == '5':
        print("Quitting program")
        quit()
    else:
        print("I did not understand that... Please try again")

menu(Parent)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to use class inheritance, then I think the following is what you are looking for:

```py
class Parent():
    
    addressbook = list()
    
    def create(self):
        create_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to create.
                           ''')
        self.addressbook.append(create_contact)
        print("Successfully added")
        return
    def remove_contact(self, remove_contact):
        remove_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to remove.
                            ''')
        if 'remove_contact' in addressbook:
            print(self.addressbook.remove(remove_contact))
        else:
            print("Error, 'search_contact' not found in the list")
        return remove_contact
    def search(self):
        search_contact = input('''Please input the details of the contact you would like to search for.
                            ''')
        if 'search_contact' in self.addressbook:
            print("'search_contact' found in Address Book")
        else:
            print("Error, 'search_contact' not found in the list")
        return
    def display_contacts(self):
        print("Displaying contacts....", self.addressbook)
        return

class Menu(Parent):
    def run(self):
        menu = input('''Address book to store friends contact
       -------------------------------------------------------------
       -------------------------------------------------------------
       Select an option...
       1 - Add/Update contact...
       2 - Display all contacts...
       3 - Search...
       4 - Delete contact...
       5 - Quit
        ''')
    
        if menu == '1':
            self.create()

        elif menu == '2':
            self.display_contacts()

        elif menu == '3':
            self.search()

        elif menu == '4':
            self.remove_contact(remove_contact)

        elif menu == '5':
            print("Quitting program")
            quit()
        else:
            print("I did not understand that... Please try again")
            
new_menu = Menu()
```

Then whenever you want to call the menu:

```py
new_menu.run()
```